# How to delete a WooCommerce coupon programmatically when a product bundle is deleted?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, woothemes

I have a custom post type **Bundles**, to create **woocommerce product bundles**. With each Bundle, there is also an option to create "Discount Coupons" which applies to that Product Bundle.

Now I want to delete any associated coupon to a Product Bundle whenever a Bundle is deleted. (Bundle is a custom post type and Coupon is also a post type in woocommerce)

How can I delete a coupon from database when a Bundle, to which the coupon is linked to, is deleted?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`before_delete_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/before_delete_post). Check if the deleted post is you product bundle post type and then query all coupons linked to this product bundle using get_posts with meta_key. If you have all these coupons just loop through them and delete them too using [`wp_delete_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post).